# Mocking local storage with jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, mocking, jasmine, local-storage

I'm using `Mocha` for my unit tests, but there isn't (is it?) a way to mock `localStorage` calls so I'm trying `Jasmine`.

I get a strange error when I mock my localStorage exactly as it is described in the Jasmine documentation.

Here is my code:

```
describe("Unit: Testing Connection Controller", function() {
    var foo, bar = null;

    beforeEach(function() {

        foo = {
            setBar: function(value) {
                bar = value;
            }
        };
        spyOn(foo, 'setBar');

        foo.setBar(123);
    });

    it('should set the domain value in the local storage', function() {

    });
});
```

And I get this error:

```
Error: Spies must be created in a before function or a spec
```

I'm using `PhantomJs` but I get the same error when I'm testing with `Chrome`.

Any idea of where it could come from ?

Comment: I also get this error with PhantomJS and Firefox.